# Llamar varios controladores y en distintos bloques Twig y Slim

Tags: php, twig, slim

Estoy empezando con un proyecto que utiliza SLIM (v4) y que es básicamente un panel de administración.

Querría tener (si es posible ya que estoy empezando con dicho framework) un controller que me pinte el menú y otro controller que se encargue de mostrar las secciones del panel.

Los tengo en mi carpeta `src/Controller` pero no sé cómo gestionar las llamadas y pintarlas con `Twig`.

MenúController :

```
namespace App\Controllers;

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;

use Slim\Views\Twig;

class MenuController{
    
    function generaMenu(Request $request, Response $response, $args){
        $view = Twig::fromRequest($request);
        $params = [
            "titleNav"=>"Home",
            "link"=>"/"
        ];

        return $view->render($response,"index.html",$params);

     }
}
```

HomeController:

```
namespace App\Controllers;

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response; use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;

use Slim\Views\Twig;

class HomeController{    

    function index(Request $request, Response $response, $args){
       $view = Twig::fromRequest($request);
       $params = [
        "title"=>"Bienvenido a tu panel de administracion",
        "categoria"=>"home"
       ];       

       return $view->render($response,"index.html",$params);

    }

     }
```

Mi index tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
<body>
    
    <section class="container-fluid container-base">
        <article class="row">
            <aside class="sidebar col-md-3 col-lg-2">
                <nav class="mi-menu">
                    {% block menu %}
                    {% endblock %}
                </nav>
            </aside>
            <div class="container-principal col-md-9 ms-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4 ">
                {% block main %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </article>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

¿Cómo podría realizarles las llamadas para poder gestionar ambos? He probado de todo pero no lo consigo.